# Ansible - Regex in Fetch?

Tags: regular-expression, ansible

I'm building an ansible playbook to copy a checklist from this file and moving it to another file.

I'm relatively new to ansible. Originally, I used the Copy plugin but saw Fetch may be more up my ally.

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Find Checklist
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: Find Checklist
     ansible.builtin.find:
       paths: /path/to/file/{{ ansible_hostname | upper }}/Checklist/
       patterns: '*.ckl'

- name: Copy Results
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: Copy Results
     ansible.builtin.fetch:
             src: "/path/to/file/{{ ansible_hostname | upper }}/Checklist/*.ckl"
             dest: "/path/to/directory"
```

and here are the results:

```
fatal: [fqdn]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "src": "/path/to/file/HOSTNAME/Checklist/*.ckl"
        }
    },
    "msg": "file not found: /path/to/file/HOSTNAME/Checklist/*.ckl"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fqdn    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I now know the wildcard is not supported. Someone answered I should do a loop, but I wonder if I can instead implement some form of regex?

I tried to do "src": "/path/to/file/HOSTNAME/Checklist/'RHEL8_[A-Za-z0-9]+.ckl'" with no luck.

Comment: Nothing in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) indicates that `fetch` supports anything other than literal file names. If you want to fetch multiple files you will need to use a loop (or create an archive on the remote system and `fetch` the archive).

Comment: @larsks imo your comment should be an answer

Comment: Reposted: [Ansible: Copying a checklist to a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768607/ansible-copying-a-checklist-to-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Fetch ... implement some form of regex."***

A: Use [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html). In the [rsync_opts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#parameter-rsync_opts):

- exclude all files matching '*'
- don't exclude files matching '*.ckl'

```yaml
    - ansible.posix.synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /tmp/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}/checklist/
        dest: /tmp/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}/checklist/
        rsync_opts:
          - "--include='*.ckl'"
          - "--exclude='*'"
```

For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

and the remote files

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_01 ls -1 /tmp/ansible/test_01/checklist
a.ckl
b.ckl
x

shell> ssh admin@test_02 ls -1 /tmp/ansible/test_02/checklist
c.ckl
d.ckl
y

shell> ssh admin@test_03 ls -1 /tmp/ansible/test_03/checklist
e.ckl
f.ckl
z
```

gives abridged registered result (running with --check --diff)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
    ...
    msg: |-
      .d..tp..... ./
      >f+++++++++ a.ckl
      >f+++++++++ b.ckl
    rc: 0

ok: [test_02] => 
    ...
    msg: |-
      .d..tp..... ./
      >f+++++++++ c.ckl
      >f+++++++++ d.ckl
    rc: 0

ok: [test_03] => 
    ...
    msg: |-
      .d..tp..... ./
      >f+++++++++ e.ckl
      >f+++++++++ f.ckl
    rc: 0
```

This will "fetch" the files to the controller

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/ansible/
/tmp/ansible/
├── test_01
│   └── checklist
│       ├── a.ckl
│       └── b.ckl
├── test_02
│   └── checklist
│       ├── c.ckl
│       └── d.ckl
└── test_03
    └── checklist
        ├── e.ckl
        └── f.ckl
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - file:
        state: directory
        path: "/tmp/ansible/{{ item }}/checklist"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - ansible.posix.synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /tmp/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}/checklist/
        dest: /tmp/ansible/{{ inventory_hostname }}/checklist/
        rsync_opts:
          - "--include='*.ckl'"
          - "--exclude='*'"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out
```